# This function (season) takes too much time to run, why ? and how can I improve the code?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

This function (season) takes too much time to run, why ? and how can I improve the code ?

## this is the function

```
def season_of_date(date):
    date=pd.to_datetime(date)
    x=date.year
    year = str(x)
    seasons = {'spring': pd.date_range(start='21/03/'+year, end='20/06/'+year),
               'summer': pd.date_range(start='21/06/'+year, end='22/09/'+year),
               'autumn': pd.date_range(start='23/09/'+year, end='20/12/'+year)}
    if date in seasons['spring']:
        return 'spring'
    if date in seasons['summer']:
        return 'summer'
    if date in seasons['autumn']:
        return 'autumn'
    else:
        return 'winter'

#I applied it to my dataset named dat
data['season'] = data.DateTime.map(season_of_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know exactly what is going on because you didn't post some sample rows of your dataframe.

If the goal is to determine the season from a column called 'DateTime', then I think the code below is more efficient because it avoids unnecessarily generating date ranges for every row and then testing if the date is in that range. Note that if you are using Python 3.5 or lower, thresholds should be an `OrderedDict` because the code relies on key order.

```
import datetime

def season_of_date(date):
    '''Assuming applied to column with dtype datetimens[64]'''
    year = date.year
    thresholds = {'autumn': datetime.date(year, 9, 1),
                  'summer': datetime.date(year, 6, 1),
                  'spring': datetime.date(year, 3, 1)}
    for season, threshold in thresholds.items():
        if date >= threshold:
            return season
    return 'winter'
```

So, applying this function to a sample dataset, results in the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': pd.date_range('11/21/2019', periods=20, freq='W')})
df['dates'].apply(season_of_date)

0     autumn
1     autumn
2     autumn
3     autumn
4     autumn
5     autumn
6     winter
7     winter
8     winter
9     winter
10    winter
11    winter
12    winter
13    winter
14    spring
15    spring
16    spring
17    spring
18    spring
19    spring
Name: dates, dtype: object
```